# iphone Call from the pdf on the webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, call

I want to open a pdf file in the webview

this pdf file contains lots of telephone numbers,

I want to do call that perticuler numbers when i click the one.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if the phone numbers in the PDF are hyperlinks like: tel:+3153148154

Comment: You will need to implement the UIWebViewDelegate method:- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Here you should get the url end then call the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]; method.

Comment: but will it call to any number mentioned in pdf?

Comment: Yes ass long as the numbers have the tel: URL scheme.

Comment: hey reck if i have any pdf with different web address and if they are in hyperlink can I use this? becuase it is not working there as well as phone call